# array.map() is not a function reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which stores data after splicing from an array.

```
const removedItemstax = {};
    function findAndRemove1(array, property, value) {
        array.forEach(function(result, index) {
       if(result[property] === value) {
      //Remove from array
        var removedItem= array.splice(index, 1);
        removedItemstax.push(removedItem);
      }    
    });
    }
```

When I try to get map it using below code to get distinct values `const tax = removedItemstax.map(d => d.taxId)` I'm getting an error that `.map()` is not a function.

But when I push the array `removedItemstax` to console I get to see all the elements stored within it.

I get the same error when I pass the array `removedItemstax = {}` via props after setting a state to it.

Mapping returns undefined, however pushing it directly displaying complete data assigned to the array. I am following the regular method to map.

Comment: `{}` is not an array, and thus `map` doesn't exist. use `const removedItemstax = []` instead

Comment: Apologies. The attribute stores json objects within it. Can you suggest changes through which I could map the data?

Comment: What are the contents of "array", how do you initialize "array"? Convert removedItemstax from {} to [].

Comment: By changing {} to [] .map() is being executed but I get undefined objects in the console. 

The contents are like this:`
[
  [
    {
      "taxId": 7586,
      "taxonomyName": "echinoderms",
      "keywordId": "KW-0547",
      "keywordName": "Nucleotide-binding",
      "taxonomyVisibility": "True",
      "keywordVisibility": "True",
      "taxonomyRank": "phylum",
      "keywordCategory": "Ligand",
      "spectCount": 1
    }
  ],
]`

This is the sample data in `removedItemstax`

Comment: Of course it won't work, you're a 2 dimensional list. Try `array.shift().forEach(........)`

Comment: I'm using `const removedItemstax1 = [].concat.apply([], removedItemstax);` to flatten the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason for getting `undefined` elements when mapping. This is due to a multidimensional array being stored in attribute `const removeItemstax = []`.

I'm using the below command to flatten the multidimensional array into a normal array before mapping it.

Here's the syntax:
`const removedItemstax1 = [].concat.apply([], removedItemstax);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
const removedItemstax = [];
function findAndRemove1(array, property, value) {
    array.forEach(function(result, index) {
        if(result[property] === value) {
            //Remove from array
            var removedItem = array.splice(index, 1);
            removedItemstax.push(removedItem);
        }    
    });
}
```

Instead `removedItemstax` be a object, him can to be a array